# Unable to draw using glDrawElements correctly

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to draw a rectangle and apply a texture unto it. The code was copied from a book I'm reading, I just passed to **C++**(from Java), here it is:

```
void draw(){
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4, vertices.data());//vertexSize is 4

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 2, vertices.data() + 2);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices.data());

glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

the vertices is a `std::vector` of `size 16` and the following values:
`[-0.25,-0.25,0.0,0.25,0.25,-0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25,0.0,-0.25,0.25,0.0,0.0]`
each 4 floats specifies a `vertex coord` and a `texture coord`, 
and the indices is a `std::vector` of `size 6` with the following values:
`[0,1,2,2,3,0]`
which specifies two triangles(with textures) in the vertices array.
This two arrays are always set before calling draw.

The problem is that the rendered object is not right, instead of a rectangle I have a trapezium rotated. The vectors seems correct, as I'm new to **OpenGL**, I've no idea of what is going wrong in this code.

Thank you for your attention.

---EDITED---
The opengl matrices are set right before enter the application loop:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();

glClearColor(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);

/*application loop, no more matrices use*/
```

Comment: Might be because of your matrices? Can we see what you are doing with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 4, vertices.data());//vertexSize is 4
```

Yes, there are 4 floats per-vertex. But that's not what the fourth parameter is. It's the *number of bytes* from one position to the next. That's not 4; it's `4 * sizeof(GLfloat)`.

Also:

```
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 2, vertices.data() + 2);
```

The second 2 here should also be `4 * sizeof(GLfloat)`. The byte stride for your array is the same for positions and texture coordinates.

Comment: solved, while changing the original version i removed the '*4' because they used a byte array and then converted to float, i was going waste some more hours on this, thanks!!